# Alternative of Oracle Sequence in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `MySql` table which consists a field `serial_no`. I want that, when a new row is being inserted, it should set the `serial_no` field as next of previous maximum of `serial_no`. 
Lets say, previous max of `serial_no` is 10, then the new row will be inserted with `serial_no` 11.

Below is how do I currently manage this.

```
$max_ser = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(serial)+1 as next_ser FROM widgets WHERE position='".$position."'");
if($max_ser){
    $row_ser = mysql_fetch_array($max_ser);
}      

$insert = 'INSERT INTO widgets(widget_name, widget_alias, widget_type, position, publish_to, serial, status)
        VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$alias.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$position.'", "'.$menus.'", "'.$row_ser['next_ser'].'", "'.$status.'")';
```

Can it be done in `MySql` with a single statement?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for MySql's [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute.

If you want to specify your starting point to another number, use:

```
ALTER TABLE <YOUR_TABLE> AUTO_INCREMENT = 999
```

Comment: thanks @Carl. but i need to add the serial as the next maximum serial as i mentioned. perhaps i am gonna embed a condition for determining the serial with it as well. i know about AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the serial as the next maximum serial"? If you mean the starting number, I've updated my post to demonstrate that.

Comment: I have updated my post. You will understand the scenario now.@carl

Comment: If you are attempting to set an AUTO_INCREMENT unique to your `position` values. Please read the `AUTO_INCREMENT` documentation I linked in my answer. Specifically, the part about using `AUTO_INCREMENT` with a multiple-column index.